# disable view page click selection in android application

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using view pager with fragments in my application. In that View pager contains three fragments, in the second fragment I am validating address. I want user has to enter address and validate the address then only user should go the third fragment, without entering address in the second fragment user should not click the third view page. I restricted swiping but I am unable to disable the click of view page.

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Naresh

Comment: you can handle onClickListner of tab. In that apply condition that user have validate address or not... if yes continue it or else block the excution

Comment: Please show your code..

Answer (score -1):

add this code in your page adapter class this will set disable your page adapter:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}
```